# Relation between memory and application performance at android

Tags: android, performance, memory, android-api-levels

I have something question when I tested an application which is rotate an huge image.

When I test a code on AVD with diferrent APIs, it shows performance diferrence.
I tested it with API 16, 19, 26, and API 26 is quite satisfaction but elses are not.

So I looked at logcat monitor and I found that API 26 takes only 30MB but elses  take almost 90 - 100MB.

My question is, is there any relation between application's memory and performance? If app need more memory, then app performance is going down?

And is it natural that if API level is different, then memory occupation different, too?

Comment: I suppose you meant SDK instead of API?

Comment: I mean API which can test at AVD in android studio